# XCode - adding a button with a tabbed style?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I noticed that the Twitter Iphone app utilizes the below style of button. It has tabs, and shows the current selection. This style of button is perfect for something I am trying to achieve in my own app, so I was wondering if this style of button is given to us in Xcode, or if I would have to design it manually.

Thanks!

[image: tabbed button]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Xcode provides that "thing" already, it is called [`UISegmentedControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/).

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much! No matter where I searched I couldn't find an example of that or any mention of it. Turns out I was searching for the wrong keywords. Again, thankyou